# Can't override style, element not accessible, although appears in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element in the page that was injected using jQuery. When inspecting the page code, I can clearly see the element and its Id. When trying to access it using jQuery:

```
$("#camera-1-height-specs")
```

or using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("camera-1-height-specs")
```

The element doesn't exist and I get `null` for Javascript and `[]` for jQuery. I can inspect the element in Chrome and can even see it's styles using Chrome developer console. I copy paste the exact Id and triple check myself.

I try overriding the style using CSS, which seems to be the easiest solution, but it doesn't work either:

```
<style>
 #camera-1-height-specs , #camera-2-height-specs  {
   writing-mode: initial !important;
 }
</style>
```

Here's the element as seen by Google Chrome using the developer tools:

[image]

My goal was to override the element with a new style, but nothing works. I tried accessing other page elements and I can access them, it's just that specific element that is not accessible. I try to access it after the page is fully loaded, and it still not working.

You can see in the code that I tried to override the `writing-mode` style with a different one, but if the browser doesn't recognize the element in the dome, the style can't apply to it.

My goal is to be able to override the writing-mode css style from inline, but an inline javascript code is also an option.

Comment: @LGSon, sorry, I corrected the typo mistakes. You can see that there is an inline style with !important that doesn't override the original value.

Comment: Can include `html` , `css`, `js` where `$("#camera-1-height-specs")` is called at Question ?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: @LGSon I've added the inline css code that suppose to override the original code. I assume that because I can't access it via jQuery or Javascript, the CSS has the same problem recognizing the element and that's why the CSS code doesn't work. Overriding a style should be easy, for some reason in this particular case it doesn't work, really weird, maybe I am missing something..

Comment: _"maybe I am missing something.."_ Difficult to determine with reproducing issue ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When I inspect the page code of the page you link to, I don't see the element. Using Chrome dev tools anyway.

Comment: I've added an image showing the element in Google Chrome, I can even inspect it using Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` of element at `console` is `#camera-1-height-spec` , not `#camera-1-height-specs`

Substitute selector

```
$("#camera-1-height-spec")
```

without `"s"`, for

```
$("#camera-1-height-specs")
```

Comment: I am so ashamed. Sometimes the simple answer is right in front of you and you miss it. I am too into the code to notice the tiny difference. Thanks my friend.

Comment: @IdanShechter No worries. Happens. Cheers

Comment: "downvote" description ?

Comment: "downvote", what do you mean? I voted up and accepted the answer. MY English is not that good, maybe I didn't understand.

Comment: Not @IdanShechter , [ at ] user that cast "downvote" for Answer . Believe OP is automatically notified when comment posted at Answer

Comment: If the problem is caused by a typo, you should be voting to close the question as such, not posting an answer to it.  Questions like this do not help future users.